# NullPointerException when using Predicate during static field initialization

Tags: java, java-8

Could someone explain what is causing the NPE in the following example code. It seems to be something to do with how static fields (in particular the `Predicate`) are initialized maybe, but I can't quite figure out what is going on.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Foo {
    public static List<Integer> stuff = doStuff();
    private static Predicate<Integer> bar = i -> i == 42;

    public static int howBigIsStuff(){
        return stuff.size();
    }

    private static List<Integer> doStuff(){
        // java.lang.NullPointerException 
        //    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
        List<Integer> foo = Arrays.asList(1,2,42,42).stream()
                .filter(bar)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return foo;
    }
}


import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.junit.Test;

public class FooTest {

    private static Predicate<Integer> bar = i -> i == 42;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        // This is fine
        List<Integer> foo = Arrays.asList(1,2,42,42).stream()
                .filter(bar)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        System.out.println(foo);    // [42, 42]

        Foo.howBigIsStuff();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the stacktrace? That will probably help the most.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [`JLS-12.4.2`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2). The order of static fields initialization matters. Fields are initialized in the order in which they appear in the source.

So at the moment `doStuff()` is called  `bar` is equals to default value `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling to `bar` before it has been initialized, try this:

```
public class Foo {
    private static Predicate<Integer> bar = i -> i == 42;
    public static List<Integer> stuff = doStuff();

    public static int howBigIsStuff() {
        return stuff.size();
    }

    private static List<Integer> doStuff() {
        // java.lang.NullPointerException 
        //    at java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:203)
        List<Integer> foo = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 42, 42).stream()
                .filter(bar)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        return foo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sequence of initialization is:

- Execution of method doStuff (here bar is not yet initialized)
- Assignement of stuff variable
- Assignement of bar variable

Here is how you can solve it:

```
public static List<Integer> stuff;
private static Predicate<Integer> bar;

static  {
    bar = i -> i == 42;
    stuff = doStuff();
}
```